# Hermitian interpolation problem

Tags: numerical-methods, interpolation, hermite-polynomials

Calculate the interpolation polyonmial $p$ of the Hermitian interpolation problem
(i) to the data
$$x_0=0, x_1=1, y_0^{(0)}=1, y_1^{(0)}=2, y_0^{(1)}=1, y_1^{(1)}=2$$
and check the derivative values.

(ii) to the data
$$x_0=0=1, y_0^{(0)}=2, y_0^{(1)}=3, y_0^{(2)}=4, y_0^{(3)}=5$$
and check the derivative values.

$$$$

Could you give me a hint with the formula because I am confused about how to fing the desird polynomial? Do we maybe use the Lagrange or Newton polynomial?

$$$$

---

I read the example in the links and I tried to do that we the divided difference method :

$$\begin{matrix}z_0=0 & f[z_0]=1 & & & \\ & & \frac{f'(z_0)}{1}=1 & & & f[z_2,z_1,z_0]=0\\ z_1=0 & f[z_1]=1 & & & \\ & & f[z_2,z_1]=\frac{f(z_2)-f(z_1)}{z_2-z_1}=1 & & & & f[z_3,z_2,z_1,z_0]=1\\ z_2=1 & f[z_2]=2 & & & \\ & & \frac{f'(z_3)}{1}=2 & & & f[z_3,z_2,z_1]=1\\ z_3=1 & f[z_3]=2 & & & \end{matrix}$$

Then do we use the formula $$p(x)=f(x_0)+f'(x_0)(x-x_0)+\frac{1}{2}f''(x_0)(x-x_0)^2+\frac{f(x_1)-f(x_0)-f'(x_0)(x-x_0)-\frac{1}{2}f''(x_0)(x_1-x_0)^2}{(x_1-x_0)^3}(x-x_0)^3$$ ?

Comment: So we either use the Lagrange polynomial or the divided differences? @Moo

Comment: As for your second comment : yes @Moo

Comment: So one way is to use Lagrange polynomials and an other way os to use divided differences, right? @Moo

Comment: I added my attempt above in the question, with the way of divided differences. Is my attempt correct ? @Moo

Comment: Is the formula of $p(x)$ correct? At the second derivatives do we use the divided differences? @Moo

Comment: So which is the formula of polynomial where we substitute the divided differences? @Moo

Comment: Ok! I will wait! Thank you! :-) @Moo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are given the data

$$x_0=0, x_1=1, y_0^{(0)}=1, y_1^{(0)}=2, y_0^{(1)}=1, y_1^{(1)}=2$$

We create the [*divided difference*](http://www.personal.psu.edu/jjb23/web/htmls/sl455SP12/ch3/CH03_4B.pdf) table.

[image]

Using your results (table looks skewed, it should be a nice diagonal like the notes)

$$\begin{matrix}0 & 1 & & & \\ & & 1 & & & 0\\ 0 & 1 & & &\\ & & 1 & & & & 1\\ 1 & 2 & & & \\ & & 2 & & & 1\\ 1 & 2 & & & \end{matrix}$$

The Hermite Interpolating Polynomial using the Divided Difference form is given by (see linked notes for an alternate view)

$H_{2n-1}(x) = f(x_0) + (x-x_0)f[z_0,z_1] + (x-x_0)^2f[z_0, z_1,z_2] + \ldots + (x-x_0)^2\ldots (x-x_{n-1})^2 (x-x_n)f[z_0,z_1,\ldots,z_n]$

We can write the Hermite Interpolating Polynomial using the values across the topmost diagonal and this formula.

$$P_3(x) = 1 + (x-0)(1) + (x-0)^2(0) + (x-0)^2(x-1)(1) = x^3-x^2+x+1$$

You should try examples $2a$ and $2b$ to make sure you follow in [*these notes*](https://math.berkeley.edu/%7Eqadeer/teaching/Su17Math128A/Homework%204%20Solutions.pdf) and the example that calculates $H_5(1.5)$ in the linked notes above.

Lastly, it is important to understand that the derivation here includes the Lagrange interpolating Polynomial and derivative information and it can be calculated that way (a little lengthier, but maybe less error prone). See this [*worked out example*](http://web.mnstate.edu/jamesju/Fall2012/Content/M450HermiteInterp.pdf) and try it.